# ecmascript-6 import/export const array

Tags: ecmascript-6

i have a module Module.js

**Portlet.js**

```
const Colors=["blue","yellow"];
const Colors2={
    mycolors:["black","green"]
}
export default class test{};
export {Colors,Colors2}
```

now i want use Colors and Colors2 from another Module.

**Other.js**

```
import {Colors} from "./Module.js"
import {Colors2} from "./Module.js"
```

But, when i try use they always i get Module.Colors/2 is undefined! 
is it possibile export a const and reuse inside another module?Yes, how to?

Comment: There is no reason this should not work, so something else must be going on. Why do you say that `Module.Colors` is undefined? In the importing module, it would be just `Colors`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be importing from `Portlet.js` since that was what you said the name of the file was?

Answer (score 0):

Import and export are ok, all problems are guilty from react-docgen